# Administrative download for windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows-10

I have a small at home computer repair business.  Where can I download an upgrade for windows 10 that I can use LEGALLY to update computers from 7 or 8 without having to download all the packages for each machine?

Comment: The Windows 10 media creation tool: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Just download the [media creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) directly from Microsoft, then launch he setup from the created disk, this question does not really show very much research effort on your part.

Comment: If you use the [link from the other comments](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and change the user agent to "Linux" it offers you to download the Windows 10 ISO file ([source](https://tqdev.com/2016-windows-10-clean-install))